# google maps v3 setting marker title dynamically

Tags: google-maps

I have [this](http://www.buscocolegio.com) school searcher; to plot the schools found I get their latitudes and longitudes along with their names:

```
<%  String[] latitudes=(String[])request.getAttribute("latitudes");
String[] longitudes=(String[])request.getAttribute("longitudes");
String[] names=(String[])request.getAttribute("names");
if(latitudes!=null){
    for (int i=0; i<latitudes.length; i++) { %> 

    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= latitudes[i] %>,<%= longitudes[i] %>);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
    var title = <%= names[i] %>;
    marker.setTitle(title.toString());

<% }
}%>
```

you can set the latitude and longitude of the marker dynamically, but if you try to set the title it doesn´t work and the map is not displayed

so, anybody knows how to solve this problem?
thanks in advance!!

Comment: `for (int i = 0` should be `for (var i`, I tried your code and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/Myydv/ The title appears when the mouse cursor is over the marker. Check the output of <%= names[i] %>

Comment: SOLVED!

I don't know why (perhaps cause it's a String) but you have to pass the variable of the title between simple quotes:

var title = '<%= names[i] %>';
marker.setTitle(title);

and it works!! Really really hard to figure it out when you have just passed latitude and longitude (String too) without simple quotes...

BYE and thanks for your help

Comment: Heitor Chang, as you can see the for loop is inside a scriptlet, that is, Java code, so it is correct. Of course if it would has been Javascript, use var instead of int